# ¿Cómo añadir un dropdownMenu dentro de otro? Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-3, django-templates

Estoy intentando añadir un menú desplegable dentro de otro utilizando Bootstrap pero al seleccionar el segundo cierra el menú directamente.

### Template

```
<li><a href="" id="dropdownMenuConfiguacion" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Configuracion <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuConfiguracion">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="" id="dropdownMenuUsuarios" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Usuarios <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuUsuarios">
                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{% url 'usuarios' %}" title="Gestión de Usuarios">Todos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'usuarios' %}" title="Gestión de Usuarios">Solicitudes boutique</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
           </li>                 
      </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: En el siguiente enlace puedes ver un pequeño snippet que te permite realizar la tarea que comentas. https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3

Comment: Saludos, se refiere a algo como esto: [Mire esta imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzOHy.png) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Twitter Bootstrap v3]**

Para crear un menú desplegable de nivel n con `Twitter Bootstrap v3`,

- Mire aquí los demos del menú desplegable n-level [v3.0.0](http://jsfiddle.net/chirayu45/YXkUT/16/) | [v3.1.1](http://jsfiddle.net/chirayu45/Khh4C/1/) | [v3.3.0](http://jsfiddle.net/chirayu45/e02t2jcc/1/)

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-menu>li /* Para evitar la selección de texto */
{   position:relative;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
    /* Las reglas a continuación no están implementadas en los navegadores todavía */
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu 
{
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display:none;
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-top-left-radius:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    border-left-color:#fff;
    box-shadow:none;
}
.right-caret:after,.left-caret:after
 {  content:"";
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.right-caret:after
{   border-left: 5px solid #ffaf46;
}
.left-caret:after
{   border-right: 5px solid #ffaf46;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu > li > a.trigger").on("click",function(e){
        var current=$(this).next();
        var grandparent=$(this).parent().parent();
        if($(this).hasClass('left-caret')||$(this).hasClass('right-caret'))
            $(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
        grandparent.find('.left-caret').not(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
        grandparent.find(".sub-menu:visible").not(current).hide();
        current.toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(".dropdown-menu > li > a:not(.trigger)").on("click",function(){
        var root=$(this).closest('.dropdown');
        root.find('.left-caret').toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
        root.find('.sub-menu:visible').hide();
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown" style="position:relative">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Click Aquí <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 1</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 2</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="trigger right-caret">Level 3</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Level 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

El Resultado seria el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Fuente SO: [[Twitter Bootstrap v3]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18025399/8933039)

Tal ves te sirve de ayuda, Saludos.

Comment: muy buena respuesta, gracias.

Comment: @FDelgado considere votar a favor si le ha sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
  
  <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                        <a className="dropdown-toggle" href="/" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        nivel 1.1
                      </a>
                      <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">nivel 2</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">nivel 2</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">nivel 2</a>
                      </div>
                        </li>


                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                        <a className="dropdown-toggle" href="/" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        nivel 1.2
                      </a>
                      <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">nivel 2.2</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">nivel 2.2</a>
                      </div>
                        </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

RESULTADO:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]